# Session Expire issue in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created mvc application.. In that i have write code for update web.config.i.e

```
try
{
    //// Helps to open the Root level web.config file.
    Configuration webConfigApp = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    AppSettingsSection objAppsettings = (AppSettingsSection)webConfigApp.GetSection("appSettings");
    //Edit
    if (objAppsettings != null)
    {
        ////Modifying the AppKey from AppValue to AppValue1
        objAppsettings.Settings["DaysToKeepJob"].Value = model.Keepjobsfolders.ToString();
        objAppsettings.Settings["DeleteLocalStoreStudies"].Value = model.DeleteLocalStoreStudies.ToString();
        objAppsettings.Settings["ManualBurnerNoOfCopies"].Value = model.ManualNumberofCopies.ToString();
        objAppsettings.Settings["DefaultBurner"].Value = model.DefaultBurner.ToString();
        objAppsettings.Settings["AutoBurnerNoOfCopies"].Value = model.AutoNumberofCopies.ToString();
        objAppsettings.Settings["SmartDisk"].Value = model.chkSMARTDisk.ToString();
        objAppsettings.Settings["ForcetodefaultTransfer"].Value = model.chkKeepjobsfolders.ToString();
        ////Save the Modified settings of AppSettings.
        webConfigApp.Save();
    }
    if (diskType.Title != null)
    {
        var res = DiskTypeSave(diskType);
    }
    return Json(new { Status = "Success", Msg = "Rules Saved Successfully." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but after this line **webConfigApp.Save();** my session i.e **Session["UserAccessRights"]** get null . i know because of updating web.config it get null.

Please suggest to maintain session even web.config updates

Comment: Don't modify your web.config file. Store your configuration elsewhere: a separate JSON or XML file, database, or key/value pair storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you change the `web.config` the application is restarted in IIS.

You can do one of the things below :

1. Use another settings file, a xml, json, etc. to store those values
2. Use the database to store those settings per user
3. Use SQL server for saving sessions or a state server, not in-memory (default)

Answer (score 0):

For this you first have to keep Sessions copy into local variable and then assign again. But for this you have to keep Session.SessionId copy also, because on new session it sets again.